# I ran the time profiler on my SpriteKit game and it is showing abnormally high CPU usage.

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, instruments, profiler

While working on my SpriteKit game I recently decided to run the profiling tools (which I just discovered) on my app. They are showing CPU usage of close to 90%! I am trying to understand where to begin looking for the slowdown to try and fix it. It is also causing the device power usage to be at "very high".

While running the profiler I displayed debug information which is as follows:

`Nodes: 144`
`Draws: 29`
`60.0fps`

It looks like  most of the time ( 64.1%) is spent inside:
`__51-[SKView_vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke`

I'm attaching the profiler readout if that helps.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes will make it easier to find the areas in your code with high CPU usage. The only thing I can tell you to check from your screenshot is to make sure you are not doing too much inside the scene's update() method.